# Font-awesome-rails helper not found within rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, font-awesome

I'm experiencing a problem with using the font awesome `fa_icon` helper when testing another helper with rspec. Within the app, the helper within the helper, works as intended; however, when I run our rspec tests for the helper that uses `fa_icon` it fails.

This is a simplified version of what the helper does:

```
def helper
  if condition
    fa_icon "some-icon"
  else
    fa_icon "some-other-icon"
  end
end
```

Here is one of the failures stating that `fa_icon` is an undefined method.

```
Failures:

  1) ApplicationHelper#risk_flag risk level is below 3 
     Failure/Error: subject { risk_flag(risk_level) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `fa_icon' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x000000081ed900>
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:84:in `risk_flag'
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:83:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Do I need to include font-awesome-rails in the spec support files in some special way? I've included it in the Gemfile in all environments.

Currently using ruby 2.1.1p176 and here is the output from `bundle list | grep '\(rails\)\|\(awesome\)'`

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.0.4)
  * actionpack (4.0.4)
  * activemodel (4.0.4)
  * activerecord (4.0.4)
  * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
  * activesupport (4.0.4)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (3.1.1)
  * addressable (2.3.6)
  * arel (4.0.2)
  * bcrypt (3.1.7)
  * bourbon (3.2.0)
  * builder (3.1.4)
  * bullet (4.8.0)
  * bundler (1.6.1)
  * cancan (1.6.10)
  * capybara (2.2.1)
  * capybara-webkit (1.1.0)
  * chosen-rails (1.1.0)
  * chunky_png (1.3.0)
  * coderay (1.1.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * compass (0.12.6)
  * compass-rails (1.1.7)
  * countries (0.9.3)
  * css_parser (1.3.5)
  * cucumber (1.3.14)
  * cucumber-rails (1.4.0)
  * currencies (0.4.2)
  * daemons (1.1.9)
  * database_cleaner (1.2.0)
  * devise (3.2.4)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * docile (1.1.3)
  * dotenv (0.11.0)
  * dotenv-deployment (0.0.1)
  * easy_translate (0.5.0)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.0.3)
  * execjs (2.0.2)
  * factory_girl (4.4.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
  * faker (1.3.0)
  * fakeweb (1.3.0)
  * font-awesome-rails (4.0.3.1)
  * foreman (0.63.0)
  * fssm (0.2.10)
  * geocoder (1.2.0)
  * gherkin (2.12.2)
  * globalize (4.0.1)
  * headless (1.0.1)
  * highline (1.6.21)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * i18n-tasks (0.3.11)
  * jquery-placeholder-rails (2.0.7)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  * jquery-ui-rails (4.2.1)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * jwt (0.1.11)
  * kaminari (0.15.1)
  * kgio (2.9.2)
  * launchy (2.4.2)
  * libv8 (3.16.14.3)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * memcachier (0.0.2)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * mini_portile (0.5.3)
  * minitest (4.7.5)
  * multi_json (1.9.2)
  * multi_test (0.1.1)
  * neat (1.5.1)
  * nokogiri (1.6.1)
  * normalize-rails (3.0.1)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * pg (0.17.1)
  * phony (2.2.5)
  * phony_rails (0.6.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.4)
  * pry (0.9.12.6)
  * pry-rails (0.3.2)
  * quiet_assets (1.0.2)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * railroady (1.1.1)
  * rails (4.0.4)
  * rails_12factor (0.0.2)
  * rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
  * rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
  * railties (4.0.4)
  * raindrops (0.13.0)
  * rake (10.3.1)
  * ref (1.0.5)
  * roadie (2.4.3)
  * rspec-core (2.14.8)
  * rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
  * rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
  * rspec-rails (2.14.2)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.3)
  * selectivizr-rails (1.1.2)
  * shoulda-matchers (2.6.0)
  * simple_form (3.0.2)
  * simplecov (0.8.2)
  * simplecov-html (0.8.0)
  * simplecov-rcov (0.2.3)
  * slop (3.5.0)
  * sprockets (2.10.1)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
  * term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
  * terminal-table (1.4.5)
  * therubyracer (0.12.1)
  * thin (1.6.2)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread (0.1.4)
  * thread_safe (0.3.3)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timecop (0.7.1)
  * tins (1.1.0)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * twilio-ruby (3.11.5)
  * tzinfo (0.3.39)
  * uglifier (2.5.0)
  * unicorn (4.8.2)
  * uniform_notifier (1.4.0)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rspec guys were able to resolve my problems:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1007#issuecomment-41510827

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "#risk_flag" do
    context "with risk level below 3" do
      it "generates a smile icon" do
        expect(helper.risk_flag(2)).to eq("<i class=\"fa fa-smile-o\"></i>")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The main changes being that I need to call my helper off of `helper`